# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" with onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with `onclick` function.

Here's my code :

```
$('ul.listing').append('<button onclick="openInApp("test")"  class="btn btn-primary">Edit <i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>');
```

When I click the button, I have the "`Unexpected end of input`" error message. 
I try to pass variable too like this :

```
$('ul.listing').append('<button onclick="openInApp('+ edit_url +')"  class="btn btn-primary">Edit <i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>');
```

And I get the following message : `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Both errors begins at the "("

I have another function (always in the append) :

```
 $('ul.listing').append('<a href="event-details.html" onclick="saveEventID(' + data[i].ID + ');">')
```

And it works perfectlly

I don't understand

Comment: Since you used `onclick="openInApp("test")"`, only `"openInApp("` is passed to the onclick listener

Comment: Your problem is conflicting quotes, try to avoid using attribute event handlers, these are just one of several issues that come up when using them.

Comment: I know that the probleme is the quotes but how to solve it ? I try to inverse double quote and quote, to remove it, etc but still the same problem. Also why the other function worked ?

Comment: You can escape the quotes with a backspace, or use a string template, or you can bind the event handler to the element as a non-inline binding.  There are various ways to approach this issue.

Comment: Just don't use inline event attributes at all. Bind the function using jQuery `on`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To nest the string in the onclick, you can do it like below where the single quote is escaped using a backslash to prevent it from terminating the string.

```
$('ul.listing').append('<button onclick="openInApp(\'test\')"  class="btn btn-primary">Edit <i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>');
```

An alternative way to handle this can be done by passing the string through a separate data attribute:

```
$('ul.listing').append('<button onclick="openInApp(this)" data-string="yourstringhere" class="btn btn-primary">Edit <i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>');
```

and then accessing it in the onclick function like this:

```
function openInApp(element) {
    var mystring = $(element).data("string");
}
```